# getting past ReadTimeout from Python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the Home Depot website using Python and requests. Selenium Webdriver works fine, but takes way too much time, as the goal is to make a time-sensitive price comparison tool between local paint shops and power tool shops.

When I send a request to any other website, it works like normal. If I use any browser to navigate manually to the website, it also works fine (with or without session data/cookie data). I tried adding randomized headers into the request, but it does not seem to help the issue. From what I can see, it's not an issue of sending too many requests per time-period, (considering that selenium and manual browsing still works at any time.) I am confident that this specific issue is NOT because of a rate limitation.

my code:

```
from random import choice
import requests
import traceback

list_desktopagents = ['Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36']
def random_headers():
    return {'User-Agent': choice(list_desktopagents),
        'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'}

response = requests.get(
    'https://www.homedepot.com/p/BEHR-1-gal-White-Alkyd-Semi-Gloss-Enamel-Alkyd- 
     Interior-Exterior-Paint-390001/300831629', 
     headers=myheaders,
     timeout=10)
```

my error:

```
raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.homedepot.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on what else I could do to successfully receive my response? I would prefer to use Requests, but anything that runs fast unlike selenium will be suitable. I understand that im being blocked, my question is not so much 'whats happening to stop me from scraping?', but rather, 'what can i do to further *humanize* my scraper so it allows me to continue?'

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try increasing the `timeout` value. Have you tried from a different ip address? Server ban?

Comment: thank you, i increased my timeout value to 30 seconds to no avail. i have also changed ip addresses, as well as switching entire computers. im pretty confident its not ban-related.

Comment: Can you post the entire script so we can try and recreate the issue? Without the headers for example we can only guess what you are passing through. In the future please use [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I get access denied if I browse the link directly.

Comment: Check your response codes for auth or not-found codes and stop if you are being rate limited or similar.

Comment: i could be misunderstanding you because it keeps being suggested, but im pretty sure it NOT RELATED to being limited by my rate. i have selenium sending about 50 requests per minutes to this exact link, with no issues whatsoever.

Comment: Selemium is different than using request because selemium is actually using a web driver so the request being sent from something that looks more like a user than the request module, which sites can easily pick up as a scrapper. Chances are you are being rate limited/blocked by the home depot site when using requests.

Comment: I understand that im being blocked, my question is not so much 'whats happening to stop me from scraping?', but rather, 'what can i do to further *humanize* my scraper so it allows me to continue?'

Comment: Just got a response by changing the user agent in the headers. Mark as answer if it works, or let me know if it doesn't

Comment: it does not look like this is solving my issue, so im still trying to figure it out before i mark anything.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Are you getting the same timeout error? And you not getting a response? Please be descriptive

Comment: I would ask a new question to ensure that this question does not become multiple questions in one, since the scope of this question is "what can i do to further humanize my scraper so it allows me to continue" i.e get a response from the page.

Answer (score 4):

The error is coming from the User Agent. The reason why Selenium is working and not request is because Selenium is using a web driver to make the request, so it is more [humanlike](https://www.google.com/search?ei=Hf9RXOfFM6iS0PEP1N6hkA8&q=selenium%20vs%20requests&oq=selenium%20vs%20req&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0j0i22i30l4.1143.2653..3262...0.0..0.95.422.6......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.tpRGX0sQsgY) while request is much easier to be detected as a script. From [Home Depot's robots.txt page](https://www.homedepot.com/robots.txt) it doesn't look like products are allowed for scraping. I just used this code and got a response by using this code:

```
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get('https://www.homedepot.com/p/BEHR-1-gal-White-Alkyd-Semi-Gloss-Enamel-Alkyd-Interior-Exterior-Paint-390001/300831629', headers=headers)    

print(response.content)
```

By using these user agents you can "trick" the site into thinking you are an actual person, which is what the web driver with Selenium does.